# Возможно ли остановить анимацию при добавлении класса перед началом следующей анимации?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Есть такой код:

```
$(function () {
    let $p = $('p');

    $p.animate({
        'background-color': 'red',
        'color': 'green',
        'padding': '10px'
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $p.stop();
        $p.animate({
            'background-color': 'transparent',
            'color': 'black',
            'padding': '0'
        }, 1000);
    }, 500);
});
```

Он отлично работает. Я бы хотел написать такой же, но через добавление и удаление класса:

```js
$(function() {
  let $p = $('p');
  $p.addClass('some_class', 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $p.stop();
    $p.removeClass('some_class', 1000);
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.some_class {
  background-color: red;
  color: green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<p>Text 1</p>
```

Все то же самое, но данный код не работает - после stop() другая анимация не запускается. Почему так? Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы все работало отлично?

Comment: Вы путаете анимацию js и анимацию css, делайте или одно или второе. Если хотите через css то используйте анимацию css.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov, я вас плохо понял. Можете привести пример кода: как сделать так, чтобы после вызова .stop() функция $p.removeClass('some_class', 1000); работала? Сейчас она как будто не вызывается.

Comment: в вашем добавлении/удалении класса анимации нет. просто переключение фона и цвета. вы передаете туда 1000, но такого параметра функция не имеет, [у нее только один параметр](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/). Так что используйте либо анимацию полностью на js, либо на css, но на последнюю вы не сможете влиять из js.

Comment: @teran, благодаря JQuery UI в функции addClass и removeClass можно передавать второй параметр - время: https://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/ . У меня в коде было подключение JQuery UI, Но Ruslan изменил мой код, и теперь там нет подключения.

Comment: судя по истории правок у вас не было  jqueryui там нигде в вопросе.

Comment: основная загвоздка тут в том, что окончательно класс элементу метод `addClass` добавляет только когда анимация закончена. а вы пытаетесь ее остановить и убрать класс до конца анимации. То есть в момент вызова `removeClass` сам класс еще не установлен. `stop` впрочем тоже  не прерывает ее выполнение вроде.

Comment: а нет. `stop()` работает исправно, но он обрывает анимацию полностью, в результате класс не добавляется вовсе.

Comment: Я не понял вопроса, в чем тогда задача? Если убрать во втором коде `stop` все отработает само. Зачем его вообще использовать?

Comment: @RuslanSemenov, чтобы не дожидаться выполнение первой анимации, прервать ее и начать выполнять вторую анимацию.

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял то вот через классы, убираете без задержки один добавляете второй

update: Добавил еще вариант через [`.switchClass()`](https://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/)

```js
$(function() {
  let $p = $('p');
  $p.addClass('some_class', 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
  
    // Вариант №1
    // $p.removeClass('some_class');
    // $p.addClass('second_class', 1000);
    
    // Вариант №2
    $p.switchClass( "some_class", "second_class", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
    
    
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.some_class {
  background-color: red;
  color: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.second_class {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<p>Text 1</p>
```